# precedence of () is not greater than &&

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

In the following code,

```
int main() {
    int a =1, b = 2, c = 3;
    if(((a++) == 5) && ((b++) == 5) && ((c++) == 5)) {
        cout<<"inside if"<< endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    }
    cout<<a<<b<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

all increment operation should be done before doing logical operation. But execution skips increment b and c. Why logical && precede over ()? By the way, result of this code is `223`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of *short circuiting*: when the left hand side of `&&` is `false`, the right-hand side is not evaluated. The precedence, on the other hand, is the way you think it should be (and, as AnT says, it's unrelated to the behavior you're seeing): `()` has precedence over `&&`.

(Similarly, when the left hand side of `||` is `true`, the right-hand side is not evaluated.)

Comment: Awesome, i never thought this.

Comment: any way to avoid that? i want all increment to be evaluated?

Comment: @Kumar: No; there is no non-short-circuiting AND operator (there's `&`, which is a bitwise AND, but it probably doesn't do what you want). You need to assign the expressions to three `bool` variables and use those variables with `&&`, or create a function (not a macro) to which you pass the expressions.

Comment: @Kumar: the way to avoid that is to not write all your code as a single statement.  It doesn't run any slower if you break up the statements.

Answer (score 1):

> all increment operation should be done before doing logical operation

This is simply not true. There's no reason why increment operation should be done before doing logical operation and `()` does not change that in any way. As it has been stated many times before, *operator precedence* does not have anything to do with *order of evaluation*. These are two completely unrelated concepts.

At the top level, your expression has the following structure

```
<term1> && <term2> && <term3> && ... && <termN>
```

Such expressions are always evaluated in strictly sequenced left-to-right order from `<term1>` to `<termN>` (with possibly short-circuited evaluation). It is completely irrelevant what you have inside those terms: nothing inside `<term2>` will ever be evaluated before `<term1>`.